# GWT: How to make image align center in Grid

Tags: css, gwt

Here are my codes that doesnt work. The image is still at top left corner.

```
public class MyImage extends Composite{

private Grid panel;
private Image image;

public MyImage(String imageUrl){
    image = new Image(imageUrl);
    panel = new Grid(3,3);
    panel.setSize("150px", "150px");
    image.setSize("96px", "96px");
    panel.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(1, 1, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
    panel.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(1, 1, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    panel.setWidget(1, 1, image);

    initWidget(panel);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use DOM style attributes:

```
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(image.getElement(), "marginLeft", "auto");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(image.getElement(), "marginRight", "auto");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(image.getElement(), "marginTop", "auto");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(image.getElement(), "marginBottom", "auto");
```

above will place your image exactly center to the cell of the grid,and now set the image to your grid.If you further wants to place your grid exactly center to the view:

```
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(panel.getElement(), "marginLeft", "auto");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(panel.getElement(), "marginRight", "auto");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(panel.getElement(), "marginTop", "auto");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(panel.getElement(), "marginBottom", "auto");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grid, you can use flowpanel and add image on it and set the padding for the image. It will work.

Below is the code:

```
            fPnlMainContainer = new FlowPanel();
            image = new Image("info.png");


            image.setSize("96px", "96px");

            fPnlMainContainer.add(image);
            image.getElement().getStyle().setPadding(123, Unit.PX);


            initWidget(fPnlMainContainer);
```

Comment: MyImage is a wrapped class of Image. I would like the image to be exactly center no matter how large is the image is. For example, I may change the size of image, then I will need to also change the padding in your code. I would prefer nothing to do even the size of image is changed.